# How can I easily indent inline comments?

Tags: indentation

I frequently have inline comments for variables:

```
var1 = 0    # Var 1
var2 = 0    # Var 2
var3 = 0    # Var 3
var4 = 0    # Var 4
```

(This is in python, for example, but this question applies to C-Style `//` just the same.)

Sometimes it happens that as I develop I have to add new variables and they may end up being longer than the previous variables. I then have to refactor my white space from

```
var1 = 0    # Var 1
var2 = 0    # Var 2
var3 = 0    # Var 3
var4 = 0    # Var 4
variable = 234 # Var
```

to

```
var1 = 0        # Var 1
var2 = 0        # Var 2
var3 = 0        # Var 3
var4 = 0        # Var 4
variable = 234  # Var
```

or thereabouts.

Right now I line-by-line it `ciw` with the cursor in the white space and then tab a lot. Is there a simpler way to do this? `>w` and `>W` just indent the line (it honestly seems like `>` only indents line by line so I don't understand the 'subject-verb' point of it (it almost seems like `>>` is redundant)).

I would really like something built-in, like I would have expected `>w` to have worked, but if that's not the case, I suppose a plug in will do.

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, > is line-wise. But it’s particular convenient for, say, >ip or >i{

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>w` doesn't work because `>` is a line-wise operator no matter what motion you give it.

There are a few ways to accomplish the edit you're looking for:

#### 1. insertion with repeat

After you've inserted tabs/spaces to get the alignment you want, press `.` on the remaining lines.  No need to insert again.

#### 2. visual block insert

Again visually select a block (`ctrl-v3j`) then type `I` to insert.  Press `<tab>` or `<space>` to make up the spaces, then press `<esc>`. The insertion will apply to all the lines within the selection.

#### 3. visual block shift (`:help v_b_<`)

Visually select a block (press `ctrl-v`) downwards from the first # (`3j`).  Now type `>`.  This will shift only the text to the right of the start of the visual block selection.  This operation has downsides though, if the space needed isn't a multiple of shiftwidth, and the corresponding `<` doesn't work.

#### 4. plugin tabular.vim

Visually select the lines you want to align then type `:Tabularize /#/`.  This will look like

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /#/
```

in the cmdline.  Then the comments will become aligned.

Comment: (1) has the problem that you always have to have cursor return to the same position in the white space (I've used `.` for this purpose in conjunction with my `ciw` method but never found it satisfactory. (3) is the closest to my original conception of a solution, but you're right, it does have significant alignment problems and you can only `>` once before the text is de-selected. (4) I have literally no plug ins installed, but I will investigate tabular.vim. (2) seems to me to be the best solution and it's the closest to how I already comment out lines of code and works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [visual block mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#CTRL-V): Move to the first `#` which you want to indent, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, select all the lines you care about and the use [<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#blockwise-operators) so insert text before or after the block you selected.

The text will only appear on the first line until you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then it will also appear on the other lines.

Answer (score 1):

**Plugin** [vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi/wiki/Quick-start#select-word-or-subword-under-cursor)

E.g. to align by `#` 3 lines:

- [cursor at start of 1st line]
- `Ctrl-V`
- `jj`
- `\\c`
- `f#`
- `\\a`
- `Esc`

Note: `\\` can be other keys, in link:

> Pay attention: in this page as in others, leader- is your `g:VM_leader` (default `\\`). Also, don't trust the pics for mappings.

Comment: mnemotechnic: "a" in \\a stands for align, while "c" stands for column

Comment: I think you meant *mnemonic :)

Comment: What is the `f=` doing here? How is the plug-in aligning by `#` if you haven't specified it even once? What if I wanted to align by another character?

Comment: My mistake, usually I align "=" and not "#", the force of habit. I corrected the answer, thanks [filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden)

Comment: You are right @d-ben-knoble, thx! Sometimes even german is easier than english

Comment: "to align by another character?" That is not the question, the question is to align comments, but anyway, to align by the 1st match in each line of a "#" or whatever other char, replace "#" by that char. I repeat, 1st match. If 2nd match then "f#" would be "2f#", and so on. The hard thing is if in some lines its the x-th match, while in others the y-th. One could just add an arbitrary unique char for all lines, then align all (by this unique char), and then delete it. I am imaging HTML comments <!-- -->, by this my workaround works, but its dirty, I suggest check plugin web.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's possible to use Visual Block even if the comments are not aligned in the original text.

For example, say you want to align the comments in this block:

```
var1 = 0 # Var 1
var22 = 0 # Var 22
var333 = 0 # Var 333
var4444 = 0 # Var 4444
variable = 234 # Var
```

Into:

```
var1 = 0        # Var 1
var22 = 0       # Var 22
var333 = 0      # Var 333
var4444 = 0     # Var 4444
variable = 234  # Var
```

One easy way to do it is to use `:normal` to insert spaces at the `#` on each line, then use Visual Block and the *left shift* operator to shift all comments left, flush to a specific column at the start of a visual block.

Use the following sequence of steps:

1. Select the lines on a visual selection. For example, use `V4j` from the first line.
2. Insert enough whitespace before the `#`, which you can do with `:normal f#9i` . (Note the "space" at the end!) This will add 9 spaces before each `#` in the lines of the visual selection. If 9 is not enough, add more (like 99 or 999, as much as you want.) Note that when you type `:` with the visual selection, Vim will automatically insert the range, so the actual command is `:'<,'>normal f#9i` , but you don't need to type those characters.
3. Move to the column where you want the `#`s to be flushed to. In this case, the last line has the longest variable name, so move to two spaces after the end of that name, which is where the `#`s should be at the end. You could use `4j3E2l` to get there.
4. Start visual-block selection, pressing `Ctrl-V`.
5. Extend the visual block to the other end of the block, by moving to the first line, while staying on the same column. For example, by using `4k`.
6. Now you can use the `<` command to shift the lines left, but only until they hit the left of the visual block. Each `<` will shift them by one `'shiftwidth'` only, so you're likely to need more than one. So, to be sure, use `9<` (or `99<`, or `999<`, if you added tons of spaces in step 2.)

That should do it. This is a nifty technique and it can be helpful when you need more flexibility than what plug-ins can afford you. For example, you could easily have used this same technique to align the assignments on the `=` symbols.

Comment: Adapted from https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20670/18609