# Align a block of code on the basis of a single character

Tags: alignment

The question's title might sound a little vague, so I'll explain the situation here more clearly.
I have these lines of code in a file which I want to align with respect to the character `=`.

```
const service = require('./service');
const baseService = require('./baseService');
const config = require('../config');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const errors = require('../errors');
```

I want the above lines to somehow look like this

```
const service     = require('./service');
const baseService = require('./baseService');
const config      = require('../config');
const Promise     = require('bluebird');
const errors      = require('../errors');
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask. I want all the `=` characters to lie in the same column and shift the after-coming code accordingly. What can I do to achieve this task?

A plugin capable of doing this would be nice, but it'd be great if I could do this without the aid of any plugin. That way I'd also learn something.

Comment: Have a look at the Align plugin by Chip Campbell. You can find the most up-to-date version at <http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ALIGN>.

Comment: I am pretty sure we have several duplicates recommending [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), [vim-easi-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align), [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align), [vim-align](https://github.com/jezcope/vim-align) or one of the many other similar plugins. I don't have the time to find the duplicate questions now but I think this one should get closed.

Comment: @statox Here's an eleven-year-old question from my notes app, where I got the solution I use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154306/how-to-insert-spaces-up-to-column-x-to-line-up-things-in-columns

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're in a pinch and want to get the expressions aligned, without having to install and learn any plug-ins, here is a quick way to do it.

1. Select the lines on a visual selection. For example, if this is your whole buffer, you could use `ggVG`, but if these lines are in the middle of a file, just select appropriately. Perhaps `V4j`?
2. Insert enough whitespace before the `=`, which you can do with `:normal f=9i` . (Note the "space" at the end.) This will add 9 spaces before each `=` in the lines of the visual selection. If 9 is not enough, add more (like 99 or 999, as much as you want.) Note that when you type `:` with the visual selection, Vim will automatically insert the range, so the actual command is `:'<,'>normal f=9i` , but you don't need to type those characters.
3. Move to the column where you want the `=`s to be flushed to. In this case, line 2 has the longest variable name, so move to two spaces after the end of that name, which is where the `=`s should be at the end. If this is the whole buffer, you could use `2G2e2l` to get there.
4. Staying on that same column, move to the first line of the block. In this case, you're moving from line 2 to line 1, so `k` is enough.
5. Start visual-block selection, pressing `Ctrl-V`.
6. Move to the last line of the block. If this is the whole buffer, you could use `G`, if this is the middle of a file, you could use `4j` to go four lines down, etc.
7. (Optional) Use `$` to select until the end of the line, on *every* line of the visual block selection. **UPDATE:** This step is actually not necessary here, since `<` will work correctly even if you don't select lines to the end. Using `$` is important when using e.g. `A` to append to the end of all lines though.
8. Now you can use the `<` command to shift the lines left, but until they hit the left of the visual block. Each `<` will shift them by one `'shiftwidth'` only, so you're likely to need more than one. So, to be sure, use `9<` (or `99<`, or `999<`, if you added tons of spaces in step 2.)

*Voilà!*

This is a pretty cool technique and it can be helpful when you need more flexibility than plug-ins can afford you. It's a good one to learn and keep on your Vim toolbox.

Comment: Thanks. Nice trick.

Comment: Is `$` necessary?

Comment: @filbranden That's a great answer. I asked this question on stack overflow as well. Could you copy this there too?

Comment: `So, to be sure, use 9<` BTW. If you've shifted too little then the visual selection could be restored with `gv`. Also, some people use `vnoremap < <gv`, so it's possible to press `<` one after another.

Comment: @Matt, you don't have to vnoremap as `<` command is dot repeatable. So press `<` once and continue with `.` s

Comment: Thanks, indeed very nice trick!

Comment: @dedowsdi Ah indeed `$` is not needed! I was under the impression it was, as I recall blocks being shifted and spaces shuffling, but I just tested and it's not the case. I just updated my answer to point out that's not necessary here. Thanks for checking that out!

Comment: No need to go to beginning before starting visual block. o and O let you control the selection

Comment: The `gv` (reload last selection), `o` (jump.to other end of selection) and `.` (to repeat `<`) commands are indeed very useful! In fact, I used them all as I cobbled this together. But later I cleaned it up to write a "concise" answer (Vim golf style, minimize keystrokes.) It's great to keep those in your finger memory, as you need to adapt this to different situations or if you change your mind a bit in the middle of the process.

Answer (score 5):

[The answer provided by **filbranden**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20670/10604) shows the sequence in general. Though, it is quite complicated. The most interesting part there is command `normal`. So, I would simplify and generalize the whole sequence of actions to the following.

1. Find a column where the characters to be aligned (`=` in this case) should be placed at on each line. The column in the example is 19.
2. Select visually the lines to be modified.
3. Use command `:normal f=30i ^[19|dw` (including the space in the middle) to apply the alignment for all the selected lines at once.

The command is applied to each line of the visual selection as follows:

- `f=` - go to the first character `=`;
- `30 ^[` - insert 30 spaces (the number may be increased if needed), `^[` -
  code of Escape (to insert it to the command line press Ctrl-v and then Esc);
- `19|` - go to the column found at step #1 of the instruction above;
- `dw` delete all the spaces till the following word which is `=` in our case.

The command may be re-applied easily to other part of code/text. Though, it would be better if it could find the column automatically (I have not found a solution for this yet).

Comment: `^[` didn't work with vim/neovim

Comment: @outoftime What did not work exactly? Did you insert the Escape code in the way that I mentioned in the answer (using Ctrl-v)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that was my problem. I have typed those characters instead of adding bare escape sequence by pressing <C-v><Esc> keys on the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Install [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align), assume you bind `<Plug>(EasyAlign)` to `ga`,  execute `gaip=`, done.

This plugin comes with a lot of predefined rule to handle common align scenarios.

Another way to do this is to use [:h !](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%21) : `!ipcolumn -t`

Comment: you mean `column` not `ipcolumn` right? (however that does not work on windows)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It's `:h !` in normal mode,  not `:h :!`. And yes, it doesn't work on windows.

Comment: @dedowsdi I didn't get the second solution. What is ipcolumn and is this vim's native command?

Comment: @KartikChauhan `:h !` is a valid normal mode operator, it `Filter {motion} text lines through the external program {filter}`. In this case, `{motion}` is `ip`, `{filter}` is `column -t`.