# Move Lines in a File to the same Column

Tags: formatting

For example I have this file:

```
abc line1
def line2
ghijk line3
lmno line4
pqrstu line5
vwxyz line6
```

I want to format the file to look like this:

```
abc    line1
def    line2
ghijk  line3
lmno   line4
pqrstu line5
vwxyz  line6
```

and all that without external tools please, only pure vim/neovim. So this is not allowed:

```
:%!column -t
```

Comment: *"So this is not allowed"* - why not? Do I also have to be blindfolded and have my arms tied behind my back?

Comment: That’s my go-to solution! It may not work on Windows without some effort, though, which would be a reasonable restriction. Please clarify.

Comment: My earlier comment may have been slightly sarcastic. Let me explain: by disqualifying some answers beforehand, you're making your question less useful for future readers who may not have the same restrictions. You are free to accept an answer that does not use external tools.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @Friedrich funny said xD No but hmmm you got a point. My though behind asking like this is to improve my vim knowledge. I will continue to use `%!column -t`, but sometimes people come up with genius ways to solve a problem and then I learn one or another thing. Also I like to rely less and less on external tools. But yeah you made a good point. I will stop asking questions like this :)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt yeah sorry I was busy the last couple of days^^

Comment: No problem. I'm patient but I'm fighting against the unresolved questions :-)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20670/18609 it's a nice building block to learn to do complex formatting using only pure Vim/NeoVim. In your case, you can use `W` instead of `f=` or `fl` to get to the second word while adding spacing for aligning. I hope you find that helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
%s/\v^(\S*)\s/\=submatch(1) . "       "[1:7 - strcharlen(submatch(1))]/
```

Where:

- `\=` makes that the substitution is an expression and not a 'literal'
- The expression `submatch(1) . "       "[1:7 - strcharlen(submatch(1))]` is

  - `submatch(1)` the first word
  - `"       "[1:7 - strcharlen(submatch(1))]` a string of 7 white spaces from which we take only `7 - strcharlen(submatch(1))` characters to fill the gap knowing that the first word takes `strcharlen(submatch(1))` characters

Or:

```
%s/\v^(\S*)\s/\=submatch(1) . join(map(range(7 - strcharlen(submatch(1))), {key -> ' '}), '')/
```

But of course there are popular plugins to format columns:

- [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align)
- [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- [vim-lion](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion)

Comment: Love the way you solved it. But can you please explain it a little further, for example what is this ` "       "[1:7 - strcharlen(submatch(1))]/` part? ^^

Comment: I have added some explanations. Feel free to ask for more ;-)

Comment: Ahhh of course how couldn't I understand yesterday^^ Beautiful way to solve it :) Also the Plugins are really cool, I am gonna have a look at them when I have more time. One last question: You seem to are really good at vim, what are your top 3 Plugins you use all the time? :)

Comment: I'm using a lot of plugin (52 at the moments). But there are three that I advice to use when you start Vim would be [vim-highlightedyank](https://github.com/machakann/vim-highlightedyank), [traces](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim), [vim-wilder](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim) the first help you to yank without using the visual mode, the second help you with substitute and the third help you using the commands.

Comment: Plugin recommendation is not the topic of this site. I have quickly prepared a small [plugin page](https://vds2212.github.io/plugins.html) with a list of widely used plugins plus some of my personal preferences ;-) If you like it I'll try to enrich it :-)

Comment: Yeah I know it is not the topic of this site, I am gonna delete my comments after you have read them. But I just had to know^^ And btw I love just how many people you are helping out here (including me, you helped me already quiet a few times^^). Thanks for the list :)

Comment: It is my pleasure :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are Ex commands "allowed"?

If `expandtab` is on:

```
:[range]s/ /\t/ | retab
```

If it is off:

```
:set et | [range]s/ /\t/ | retab | set et!
```

See `:help 'expandtab'`, `:help :retab`, `:help :s`, `:help :range`, and `:help :set-!`.

Comment: This is also a nice answer, quick and easy. But it wouldn't work if one of your lines are longer, lets say 10 characters, wouldn't it?^^